# Javascript image change with slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create something where an image can be changed by using a slider. However it's not your ordinary carousel. I want an image, in this case a wireframe, and if you slide the slider from right to left another image, the actual mockup, appears. See the image below for an more acurate description

i know how to create a slider with javascript but i'm not sure how i'm going to achieve this effect using this.

Comment: So why don't you just create the slider in javascript and put 2 pictures as the content of the slider, one wireframe and one mockup

Comment: that was my inital thought, however creating a slider with for example 1 as the mockup.png and 0 as the wireframe.png doesn't create this visual effect i want to achieve shown in the picture

Comment: You just need to modify your slider to make it work. For example when sliding, the right image cover the left image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some resources found on Google:

- http://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty
- https://juxtapose.knightlab.com/
- https://github.com/kavyasukumar/imgSlider
- https://github.com/koenoe/cocoen
- https://github.com/CodyHouse/image-comparison-slider
- https://github.com/slamcode/cato.js
- https://github.com/jotform/before-after.js

Comment: thanks the first link seems to be what i wanted to achieve, i'll give it a shot!